# Oracle SQL where regexp_like and not like

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I would like to query a table where I am comparing against a regular expression and then of those results I want to filter out any that begin with 999

Here's the query I have, but this returns no results:

```
Select * FROM my_table 
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(my_row, '[a-zA-Z]') 
AND my_row NOT LIKE '999%'
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong with this? I know that I should be getting several results.

Sample date would be like the following...

```
my_row
______

12345
45673
G12354
1234B
999RT
```

Comment: The query looks correct to me. Can you provide some actual sample data  from `my_table`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given this test data:

```
create table my_table (id number, my_row varchar2(10));

insert into my_table values (1, '7878')
/
insert into my_table values (2, 'THIS')
/
insert into my_table values (3, 'and this')
/
insert into my_table values (4, '999NOTthis')
/
```

Your query returns these results:

```
ID     MY_ROW
--     ------
2      THIS
3      and this
```

Here's [a SQL Fiddle to prove it](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a5cd2/1).

These seem to be the rows we would expect to be returned by your logic so the problem is clearly in your data.

Comment: I'll give this answer the tick as you confirmed that my query was correct and it was a problem with the data. It turns out that the records on the data leading spaces (eg '  999RT') so I had to trim first.

Answer (score 1):

Given your sample data, this query:

```
with my_table as (
  select '12345' as my_row from dual union all
  select '45673'           from dual union all
  select 'G12354'          from dual union all
  select '1234B'           from dual union all
  select '999RT'           from dual
)
select * from my_table
where regexp_like(my_row, '[a-zA-Z]') 
and my_row not like '999%'
```

Yields

```
MY_ROW
------
G12354
1234B
```

So I can second [APC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11610929/521799), saying that the problem is elsewhere